# Insert multiple values into vector

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

I have a `std::vector<T>` variable. I also have two variables of type T, the first of which represents the value in the vector after which I am to insert, while the second represents the value to insert.

So lets say I have this container: `1,2,1,1,2,2`

And the two values are 2 and 3 with respect to their definitions above. Then I wish to write a function which will update the container to instead contain:

```
1,2,3,1,1,2,3,2,3
```

I am using c++98 and boost. What std or boost functions might I use to implement this function?

Iterating over the vector and using std::insert is one way, but it gets messy when one realizes that you need to remember to hop over the value you just inserted.

Comment: Are you aware of the efficiency issues of such an algorithm with a std::vector? Each time you insert a value, the rest of the vector is copied. Because the std::list might not be a good solution, I can think of an in-place algorithm that move element only once. But I don't know if it exists in Boost.

Comment: I didn't speak about reallocating the vector. There is no extra spaces between elements, one of the main characteristic of the vector is to have contiguous data. Of course if you always insert at the end, the problem doesn't occur. Well, see my answer for an algorithm that works in-place.

Comment: @PierreT.: Sorry, I didn't understand what you were getting at. Yes, you want to do this like BenjaminLindley's answer shows: put the data into a new vector so you're always adding data at the end, then swap the content back into the original vector.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Well, as I said, I have a solution that doesn't use the double of memory and only copy once the elements (like in the Benjamin answer).

Comment: @PierreT.: If you mean using `std::list`, then you're sort of right: it doesn't use double the memory -- it uses *triple* the memory. Each node contains two pointers in addition to the actual data, and in a typical case, all three are the same size.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Does my answer is invisible or you just don't want to look at it?

Comment: @WhozCraig You deleted your answer before I could reply. Yes, I was talking about `v.end()`. See [what happens](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d543d31396a0a2ad2045fd2e02d7d709-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51) with gcc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I would probably do:

```
vector<T> copy;
for (vector<T>::iterator i=original.begin(); i!=original.end(); ++i)
{
    copy.push_back(*i);
    if (*i == first)
        copy.push_back(second);
}
original.swap(copy);
```

Put a call to reserve in there if you want.  You know you need room for at least `original.size()` elements.  You could also do an initial iteraton over the vector (or use `std::count`) to determine the exact amount of elements to reserve, but without testing, I don't know whether that would improve performance.

Comment: I'd `reserve()` the original amount of memory, but otherwise this looks good. If I was pressed for performance, I would additionally try to swap/move elements from one container to the other.

Answer (score 3):

I propose a solution that works in place and in O(n) in memory and O(2n) time. Instead of O(n^2) in time by the solution proposed by Laethnes and O(2n) in memory by the solution proposed by Benjamin.

```
// First pass, count elements equal to first.
std::size_t elems = std::count(data.begin(), data.end(), first);
// Resize so we'll add without reallocating the elements.
data.resize(data.size() + elems);
vector<T>::reverse_iterator end = data.rbegin() + elems;
// Iterate from the end. Move elements from the end to the new end (and so elements to insert will have some place).
for(vector<T>::reverse_iterator new_end = data.rbegin(); end != data.rend() && elems > 0; ++new_end,++end)
{
  // If the current element is the one we search, insert second first. (We iterate from the end).
  if(*end == first)
  {
    *new_end = second;
    ++new_end;
    --elems;
  }
  // Copy the data to the end.
  *new_end = *end;
}
```

This algorithm may be buggy but the idea is to copy only once each elements by:

1. Firstly count how much elements we'll need to insert.
2. Secondly by going though the data from the end and moving each elements to the new end.

Comment: data.resize(data.size() + elems); is not better than vector result;  result.reserve(...); ... original.swap(result). Calculating the resulting size, first, is good, I think

Comment: And why not? I use half of the memory. If original is a 10Mb vector, I'll use only 10Mb. If you use a temporary vector, you will use 20Mb.

Comment: @ Pierre T.: C++ has no realloc

Comment: It depends.  If the original vector has enough capacity, then no extra space will be required.  If it doesn't, then the call to resize will require enough space to keep the original buffer alive while it copies over elements to the new buffer. In my algorithm, the extra space is always required.

Comment: @DieterLücking you mean that internally, the implementation of the std::vector does not use any realloc mechanism?

Comment: If that `resize()` changes the vector `capacity()` it will invalidate the `end` iterator you just saved. This code is not good.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I probably would do:

```
typedef ::std::vector<int> MyList;
typedef MyList::iterator MyListIter;

MyList data;

// ... fill data ...

const int searchValue = 2;
const int addValue = 3;

// Find first occurence of searched value
MyListIter iter = ::std::find(data.begin(), data.end(), searchValue);

while(iter != data.end())
{
    // We want to add our value after searched one
    ++iter;

    // Insert value and return iterator pointing to the inserted position
    // (original iterator is invalid now).
    iter = data.insert(iter, addValue);

    // This is needed only if we want to be sure that out value won't be used
    // - for example if searchValue == addValue is true, code would create
    // infinite loop.
    ++iter;

    // Search for next value.
    iter = ::std::find(iter, data.end(), searchValue);
}
```

but as you can see, I couldn't avoid the incrementation you mentioned. But I don't think that would be bad thing: I would put this code to separate functions (probably in some kind of "core/utils" module) and - of course - implement this function as template, so I would write it only once - only once worrying about incrementing value is IMHO acceptable. Very acceptable.

```
template <class ValueType>
void insertAfter(::std::vector<ValueType> &io_data,
                 const ValueType &i_searchValue,
                 const ValueType &i_insertAfterValue);
```

or even better (IMHO)

```
template <class ListType, class ValueType>
void insertAfter(ListType &io_data,
                 const ValueType &i_searchValue,
                 const ValueType &i_insertAfterValue);
```

**EDIT:**

well, I would solve problem little different way: first count number of the searched value occurrence (preferably store in some kind of cache which can be kept and used repeatably) so I could prepare array before (only one allocation) and used memcpy to move original values (for types like int only, of course) or memmove (if the vector allocated size is sufficient already).

Comment: @DieterLücking: Oops -- I didn't read carefully enough. I retract my previous comment -- it was simply incorrect.

Comment: Benjamin Lindley solution is better for a vector, yours is better for a list. Hence have both templates implementing a different strategy.

Answer (score 1):

In place, O(1) additional memory and O(n) time ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2dfb125866e54aba2ee252d3124ad107-013b9d3d56a6f5d1263cc1b6ad367352)):

```
template <typename T, typename A>
void do_thing(std::vector<T, A>& vec, T target, T inserted) {
    using std::swap;

    typedef typename std::vector<T, A>::size_type size_t;
    const size_t occurrences = std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), target);
    if (occurrences == 0) return;

    const size_t original_size = vec.size();
    vec.resize(original_size + occurrences, inserted);

    for(size_t i = original_size - 1, end = i + occurrences; i > 0; --i, --end) {
        if (vec[i] == target) {
            --end;
        }
        swap(vec[i], vec[end]);
    }
}
```