# Insert multiple elements at multiple offsets into an vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++14

I've got an `vector<uint32_t> values` and an `vector<std::pair<uint32_t, uint_32_t>> updates` that contains (a lot) accumulated updates to the vector, which I want to enact as cheaply as possible.

An update of `{5, 12}` should insert `12` right after the the `values[5]`, **not concerning any other modifications**, i.e. `values = {10,20,30}` and `updates = {{0,5}, {1, 6}, {2, 7}}` should result in `values = {10, 5, 20, 6, 30, 7}`.

I want to modify the vector according to the `updates` vector like this:

```cpp
static void update(std::vector<uint32_t>& values,
    std::vector<std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t>> updates) {
    std::sort(updates.begin(), updates.end(),
        [](std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t> a, std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t> b){
             return a.first < b.first;
        });
    values.reserve(values.size()+updates.size());
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < updates.size(); ++i){
        values.insert(values.begin()+i+updates[i].first, updates[i].second);
    }

}
```

If I'd allow duplicated `update[i].first`, I'd need to use `std::stable_sort` to keep the relative order.

Obviously, this code is quite slow, using `O(n^2)` time to move the remainder of the vector back one at a time. There should be a better solution.

There is a question on SO already, that is quite similar: [Insert multiple values into vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256697/insert-multiple-values-into-vector). While there is an answer that I could use to update my vector in `O(1)` space and `O(n)` time, the question is quite old using c++03 and I wanted to know if there is a modern way to do that (or even, if I could avoid calling `std::sort` beforehand).

Comment: Could be wrong but it wouldn't be the same without the sorting? Two issues I see: a) You should extend the vector and not just reserve, b) you should extend based on the max updates.first value and not updates size

Comment: without sorting I wouldn't know if the previous update moved my index or not @DimChtz

EDIT: Why should I extend by max(updates.first)? Every call to `insert` will increase my `values` by exactly one element

Comment: What kind of indices are `updates[i].first`? Because now it looks like it matters in what order you apply the update. Does `(5,12)` mean insert the value 12 at current `vec[5]`, or the one before all updates, or the one after some updates but before others, or that after all updates `vec[5]=12`?

Comment: @Quimby: Edited to (hopefully) make it clear.

Comment: What you would gain from c++11/C++14 is mostly `auto` to avoid to write verbose `std::vector</**/>::/*reverse_*/iterator`. Algorithm by itself won't change.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this should work. Since we know all updates, we know how much must each value be shifted to make space for the new ones. That is, exactly the amount equal to the number of updates with lower indices that the given value has. we can work from backwards, shifting the values by `|updates|` positions, insert the update with the highest index, shift the next batch by `|updates-1|` positions, insert the second-highest update...

```
static void update(std::vector<uint32_t>& values,
    std::vector<std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t>> updates) {
    std::sort(updates.begin(), updates.end(),[](auto a, auto b){
             return a.first > b.first;//From highest to lowest indices.
        });

    const std::size_t N = values.size();
    std::size_t K = updates.size();
    values.resize(N+K);
    std::size_t end = N;
    for(auto [i,v]:updates){
        //Shift the values in [i+1,end) K positions right
        std::move_backward(values.begin()+i+1,
                           values.begin()+end,
                           values.begin()+end+K);
        //Insert the update
        values[i+K]=v;
        //Preceding values are shifted only by K-1 positions
        --K;
        //Already shifted values
        end=i+1;
    }
}
```

This needs `O(u log u)` to sort the updates and `O(u+n)` to shift the old and add the new values. Only one `resize` is done. Note that `resize` zero-initializes the added values, the raw array would be slightly more efficient here. Or do some index magic with `emplace_back`.